# Password protect with apache2.conf works on files, but not on ports

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, solr

I have changed the apache2.conf so that my website requires authentication.

This works fine when typing the adress like this: www.domain.com or my_ip/

Problem is, I have Solr, which admin interface is on port 8983, so this:

```
 www.domain.com:8983/
```

does not require authorization.

How can I add this port to also be authorized?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert with Solr, but it seems to me that this admin interface is not being served through your configured apache instance. From what I see, Solr has built-in tomcat for this purpose. Have you checked the Solr wiki / documentation? You will need to configure tomcat to require authentication for this url.

Answer (score 0):

in fact there is no option for authentication on ports. 
you need to know where is the documentroot of solr in file system. 
& you can handle a basic authentication realm on that directory.

here is a complete guide to get it working, 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html 
just find the directory of Solr's documentroot.